# Customizing back button in navigationbar

Tags: configuration, navigation, sencha-touch-2, back, navigationbar

I have two questions regarding the back button in the Navigationbar element of Sencha Touch 2.

**My Code**

```
var oNavigationbar = {
        docked: 'top',

        backButton : {
            margin: 7,
            docked: "left",
            ui : 'back'
        },
        items: [
            Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
                text: "Button1"                
            },
            Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
                text: "Button2",
                align: "right",
            }

        ],
    };
```

**Question 1**
How do I stick the back button to the left side of the navigation bar?
If I set `align:"left"` Button1 is still on its left side.
But if I dock it to the left side I have to set a margin, which I rather avoid.

**Question 2**
How do I set the default text of the back button to something else then "Back".
Which configuration properties do I have to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure what you mean in q1... AFAIK Navigation Bar (as a subcomponent of Ext.navigation.View) has back button already left aligned.

Q2:

```
Ext.define('MyNavigator', {
extends: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'mynavigator',
    config: {
        defaultBackButtonText: 'Go Back',
        // back button a-la iPhone 
        // useTitleForBackButtonText: true
....
})
```

see at http://docs-devel.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-cfg-defaultBackButtonText for more info...

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks! I had set the defaultBackButtonText, on the back button instead of the navigationview....  On Q1 I'm having the problem that the back button is not always entirely to the left. In my case the Button1 is in the way so I get this set up: Button1|BackButton|Button2